# how to save your edited headers in original fasta files?

Tags: python, bash, save, fasta

hi i'am trying to edit the header of my fasta files using seqkit and i have been able to do it but i'm not able to save it!
the command i am using to edit multiple fasta files with respect to their filename and doing it with refseq-

```
for i in $(find -name \genomid); do seqkit replace -p "^(.+?) (.+?)$" --replacement '{kv}' -k proid_unique *.faa; done
```

The directory having all my fasta files is like this-
PATH:
~/PANGENOMICS/DATA1/test

FILES in the directory:

```
GCF_000016305.1_ASM1630v1_protein.faa
GCF_000220485.1_ASM22048v1_protein.faa
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa
proid_unique
genomid
```

i am finding filenames using a csv file list- genomid

```
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362402.1:WP_151362402.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362403.1:WP_151362403.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362404.1:WP_151362404.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362405.1:WP_151362405.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362406.1:WP_151362406.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362407.1:WP_151362407.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362408.1:WP_151362408.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362409.1:WP_151362409.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362410.1:WP_151362410.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362411.1:WP_151362411.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362412.1:WP_151362412.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362413.1:WP_151362413.1#0940
GCF_900635735.1_32875_B01_protein.faa:WP_151362414.1:WP_151362414.1#0940
```

the file (proid_unique) i used as key-value file to edit  the fasta headers look like this-

```
WP_151362399.1  WP_151362399.1#0940
WP_151362400.1  WP_151362400.1#0940
WP_151362401.1  WP_151362401.1#0940
WP_151362402.1  WP_151362402.1#0940
WP_151362409.1  WP_151362409.1#0940
WP_151362410.1  WP_151362410.1#0940
WP_151362411.1  WP_151362411.1#0940
WP_151362412.1  WP_151362412.1#0940
WP_151362413.1  WP_151362413.1#0940
WP_151362414.1  WP_151362414.1#0940
WP_094096600.1  WP_094096600.1#0945
WP_016530940.1  WP_016530940.1#0950
WP_000940121.1  WP_000940121.1#0951
WP_012540940.1  WP_012540940.1#0951
```

example of input-

```
>WP_151362411.1 YoaH family protein [Klebsiella pneumoniae]
MYAPQCSRSKRCFAGLPSLSHEQQQQAVERIHELMAQGISSGQAIALVAEELRATHTGEQ
IVARFEDEDEDE
>WP_151362412.1 gamma-glutamylcyclotransferase [Klebsiella pneumoniae]
MLEAIGGEWRPGYVTGTFYARGWGAAADFPGIVLDAHGPRVNGYLFLSDRLARTGPCWTT
LRRGYDRVPVEVTTDDGQQISAWIYQLQPRG
>WP_151362413.1 acid resistance repetitive basic protein Asr [Klebsiella pneumoniae]
MKKVLALVVAAAMGLSSVAFAADAASTTPSAAASHTTVHHKKHHKAAAKPAAEQKAQAAK
KHHKTAAKTGSRAESAGCKETS
>WP_151362414.1 ABC transporter permease [Klebsiella pneumoniae]
MKRAPWYLRLATWGGVIFLHFPLLIIAIYAFNTEDAAFSFPPQGLTLRWFSEAAGRSDIL
QAVTLSLKIAALSTAIALVLGTLAAGALWRSAFFGKNAVSLLLLLPIALPGIITGLALLT
AFKAVGLEPGLLTIVVGHATFCVVVVFNNVIARFRRTSWSMVEASMDLGATGWQTFRYVV
LPNLGSALLAGGMLAFALSFDEIIVTTFTAGHERTLPLWLLNQLGRPRDVPVTNVVALLV
MLVTTIPILGAWWLTRDGDSDAGNGK
```

example of output- expected and correct with above command

```
>WP_151362411.1#0940
MYAPQCSRSKRCFAGLPSLSHEQQQQAVERIHELMAQGISSGQAIALVAEELRATHTGEQ
IVARFEDEDEDE
>WP_151362412.1#0940
MLEAIGGEWRPGYVTGTFYARGWGAAADFPGIVLDAHGPRVNGYLFLSDRLARTGPCWTT
LRRGYDRVPVEVTTDDGQQISAWIYQLQPRG
>WP_151362413.1#0940
MKKVLALVVAAAMGLSSVAFAADAASTTPSAAASHTTVHHKKHHKAAAKPAAEQKAQAAK
KHHKTAAKTGSRAESAGCKETS
>WP_151362414.1#0940
MKRAPWYLRLATWGGVIFLHFPLLIIAIYAFNTEDAAFSFPPQGLTLRWFSEAAGRSDIL
QAVTLSLKIAALSTAIALVLGTLAAGALWRSAFFGKNAVSLLLLLPIALPGIITGLALLT
AFKAVGLEPGLLTIVVGHATFCVVVVFNNVIARFRRTSWSMVEASMDLGATGWQTFRYVV
LPNLGSALLAGGMLAFALSFDEIIVTTFTAGHERTLPLWLLNQLGRPRDVPVTNVVALLV
MLVTTIPILGAWWLTRDGDSDAGNGK
```

i am getting the required/expected result but this editing is not saving with this command, can someone help me figure out that how to save those editing in the original files bcz when i open those files again they were same as before with no edited header?

*Python alternative of the above command used would also be helpful*

Comment: Would you elaborate on the structure of directory tree which hold the fasta files? Please update your question instead of answering as a comment here.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with the information of directory tree. But the description is still ambigous to me. I assume the directory name is `cusid_genomid` and it contains multiple *.faa files (FASTA amino acid files). Correct?

Comment: sorry, for ambiguity, now i have edited again, i hope it's more understable now.

Comment: i did the editing in header of fasta files but the editing is not saved in original files, whenever i open my fasta files there is not edited header that i did with the alternate awk command- 
for i in $(find -name \cusid_genomid); do echo $i|\
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($2 in a) && /^>/{
  print ">"a[$2]
  next
}
1
' proid_unique FS="[> ]"  *.faa;
done

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm understanding one by one. What is the purpose of the `genomid` file? How is it related with the *.faa files existing in the directory? Can I neglect the `genomid` file just for the header editing task and process the *.faa files according to `proid_unique`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- The relevant files are `proid_unique` and `*.faa` files in current
  directory.
- We want to replace `*.faa` files by editing the header lines
  according to the key-value pairs described in `proid_unique`.
- We can forget about `genomid` file so far.

As I'm not familiar with `seqkit` command, here is an python alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import os

with open('proid_unique') as f:             # open the key-value file
    m = {k : v for k, v in [line.split() for line in f]}
                                            # create a dictionary of key-value pairs to edit

for fasta in glob.glob('*.faa'):
    org = fasta + '.O'                      # backup filename appending '.O' suffix
    os.rename(fasta, org)                   # rename the file
    with open(org) as f, open(fasta, 'w') as w:
                                            # open files to read and write
        for line in f:                      # process line by line
            line = line.rstrip()            # remove a newline character
            if line.startswith('>'):        # header line
                header = line.split()[0]    # extract the substring before a whitespace
                if header[1:] in m:         # if the header is a key in the dictionary
                    line = '>' + m[header[1:]]
                                            # then replace the line
            w.write(line + '\n')            # overwrite to the fasta file
```

It back-ups the old `*.faa` files as `*.faa.O`.
If my assumption is incorrect, please let me know.